# Remove black points in legend box executed with ggplot -Rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
values<- c("v","c")
G1<- c(1,5,1,4,0,5,0,5,1,2,0,7,5,5,1,2,1,1,5,6,2,4,0,3,0,3,3,17)
G2<- c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D","E", "E", "F", "F", "G","G", "H","H","I", "I","J", "J", "K","K", "L", "L","M", "M", "N", "N")
temperature <-c(-0.81,-0.81,-0.91, -0.91,-1.01, -1.01,-0.99, -0.99,-0.92,
                -0.92,-0.82,-0.82, -0.67,-0.67,-0.43, -0.43, -0.14,-0.14,
                 0.16,0.16, 0.48, 0.48, 0.77,0.77, 1.07, 1.07, 1.32,1.32)
data1<- data.frame(x = G2, y= G1, values) 

ylim.prim <- c(0, 20)
ylim.sec <- c(-1.5,1.5)

b <- diff(ylim.prim)/diff(ylim.sec) 
a <- (ylim.prim[1] - b*ylim.sec[1]) 
ggplot(data1,mapping =  aes(x = x, y=G1, fill = values))+
geom_bar(stat = "identity",color = "black") + 
scale_fill_manual(name = "", values =c("purple", "green"),
                  labels = c("EMPTY", "FULL")) +
geom_point(aes(y = a + temperature*b))+  
theme_classic()+  
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10,color = "black",  face = "italic"))+ 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black",size = 7,angle=90),axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black",size = 8,hjust = 1))+
theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +geom_line(aes(y = a + temperature*b),group=1, color = "#483D8B",lwd=1)+
geom_line(aes(y = a + temperature*b, group=1,color = "temperature")) +
scale_color_manual(NULL, values = "black")+
geom_point(aes(y = a + temperature*b, group=1,color = "temperature"))+ 
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~(. - a)/b,breaks = c(-1.3,-1.1,-0.9,-0.5,0, 0.5,0.9,1.1,1.3), name = "temperature")) +
theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),legend.key = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
legend.spacing = unit(-1, "lines"))+
expand_limits(y = c(0,0))+
labs(title="", x=G2, y="G")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to move the `fill = values` out of the main ggplot call and into the `geom_bar` call. This means that only the draw key from the `geom_bar` call will be used in the legend for `fill`.

Note too that `geom_bar(stat = 'identity')` is just a long way of writing `geom_col()`.

The code is poorly organised with some unnecessary repetitions, so I have tidied it up a bit here.

```r
ggplot(data1, aes(x = x, y = G1)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = values), color = "black") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = a + temperature * b, group = 1, color = "temperature")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = a + temperature * b, group = 1, color = "temperature")) +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = c("purple", "green"),
                    labels = c("EMPTY", "FULL")) +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous('G', expand = c(0, 0),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~(. - a)/b, name = "temperature",
                     breaks = c(-1.3,-1.1,-0.9, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.9, 1.1, 1.3))) +
  theme_classic() +  
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10, color = "black", face = 3),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 7, angle = 90),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 8, hjust = 1),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = NA),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA),
        legend.spacing = unit(-1, "lines"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! I have reviewed it and it helped me a lot.